# How to Dirctly read Specific lines of data from the large text file without search every line in C , or java

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a text file with some Account details in a huge size more than 7GB.Each Lines contains details of a single Accounts and other information.Here i want to read some Account details which contains first 3 charecters as "XBB". If i useed to search line by line it will take such a long time so I want to hit directly to that Particular Lines which contains the "XBB"..

Is there any Possible ways to do that in Java or VB , or VB.net

Answer (score 4):

If the lines are sorted by their first 3 characters, then you can do a binary search. This is straightforward if the lines are a fixed length. Otherwise, you will need to search for the start of each line at each step of the binary search.

If you know the index of the line, you can try going to it directly. Again, this is trivial if the lines are a fixed length; otherwise you will still have to probe and search a bit.

In Java, the tool to use for this is [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). I don't know about VB/VB.net.

Following the suggestion by Peter Lawrey, if you are willing to scan the file once, you can build an index of the offset into the file at which each 3-character prefix starts. You can then use this to very quickly get to the correct line.

Comment: +1 An alternative is to build an index of where each of the codes starts.  This would only need to be done once per file.

Comment: Hai Ted, Yes its a sorted file but Its sorted by Its 12th byte with 3 bytes long.The file is not indexed we could not index the file belongs to some rules.....                                                                Could you show me the code in java by using RandomAccessFile?

Comment: @satheeshkumar - If the file is not sorted by the characters you need to find, and if you are barred from creating an index file, I think you are out of luck. The only approach I can see is to read through the entire file. If the records are of fixed length, you can use `skip()` to avoid reading each record in its entirety, which may speed up processing a little bit. But on the average you are going to have to go through half the file for each record you want to find. I'd suggest trying to get permission to use an index file.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what language you use; the only way to find something is to search for it. You can use a search tool like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) to do the searching ahead of time, i.e., create full-text search index, or you can do the searching when you need to as you're doing it now, but you won't be able to escape the searching part.

Comment: No need for a full-text index if OP only needs to locate lines based on their first 3 characters.

Comment: The point wasn't so much about what technology to use as to note that some sort of searching, either on-the-spot or ahead-of-time, is required. The most efficient would be to create some kind of index as the file is being created. Failing that, there's nothing for it but to look through the whole file, if for no other reason than to find the newlines so the three characters after them can be examined.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if you have an Index file, and that index file contains indexes for the particular column of data you want to search on.

The other option would be to load the file into a database, like Sql Server Express, and run a sql query on it.

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expressions (regex). With these you can set an expression that contains only those specific letters. Then using a scanner it will look for only that sequence of letters.

Comment: This will not solve the problem, the file still must be read entirely (or at least until the line is found).

Comment: Hello All , Yes its a shorted file But it sorted by its 12th Byte with 3 byte long